# Combining reply and postback buttons

Tags: smooch

How do I combine action buttons of multiple types (reply and postback) within one message? Example:

```
{
   "type":"text",
   "text":"The more you know, am I right?  Would you like to learn...",
   "actions":[
      {
         "type":"postback",
         "text":"From a human",
         "payload":"Edu - human"
      },
      {
         "type":"reply",
         "text":"From content",
         "payload":"Edu - content"
      },
      {
         "type":"reply",
         "text":"From your peers",
         "payload":"Edu - community"
      },
      {
         "type":"reply",
         "text":"Something else",
         "payload":"Something else"
      },
      {
         "type":"reply",
         "text":"just to test",
         "payload":"just to test"
      }
   ],
   "role":"appMaker",
   "name":"Flowdev"
}
```

The example above is just not shown in Smooch chat. If I change first action type to reply or change other three to postback the message will be shown.

Answer (score -1):

`postback` actions can be combined with other persistent button types (`link`/`buy`/etc.)
`reply` actions cannot be combined with persistent buttons.

Comment: if you absolutely want both, you could send a second message that contains the quick-reply buttons  (just wait a second or two in between - message-order is not guaranteed on async messaging platforms)